# Help with a sort method

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

If i have an array of strings for example

`Static final String[] TEST = new String[] {
"g","a","b","t","e" };`

How would i go about sorting this in alphabetical order please?

Comment: You should read up on more Java tutorials. This is a trivial question! `=]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.util.Arrays;

Arrays.sort(TEST);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another example.

```
static final String[] TEST = "gabte".split("");
static {
   Arrays.sort(TEST);
}
```